# Using Matio Library to read a string from a .mat file into C++

Tags: c++, character

I use the matio library to input a .mat file in my C++ code.
It works nicely for numeric values; but I have problem reading character arrays.

```
  int   start[2]={0,0},stride[2]={1,1},edge[2]={1,1};
  mat_t  *mat;
  matvar_t *matvar, matvar1;

  mat = Mat_Open("test.mat",MAT_ACC_RDONLY);
  matvar = Mat_VarReadInfo(mat,"data");
  matvar1 = Mat_VarGetStructFieldByName(matvar,"name",0);
  char ptr[matvar2->dims[1]];
  edge[0] = matvar2->dims[0];
  edge[1] = matvar2->dims[1];
  Mat_VarReadData(mat,matvar2,ptr_string,start,stride,edge);
```

Mat_VarReadData writes the data from mat to ptr_string, where matvar2 is a pointer, that points to the name struct.

As mentioned, this works fine for numeric values; but with characters, I don't get the supposed charaters. Maybe the format is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me while channels is a list of string :

```
    mat_t* mat = Mat_Open(fileName, MAT_ACC_RDONLY);
    matvar_t* channels{};
    channels = Mat_VarRead(mat, (char*)"Channels");

    if (channels)
        {
            //print individual
            matvar_t** cells = static_cast<matvar_t**>(channels->data);
            printf("{\n");
            for (int i{}; i < channels->dims[1]; i++)
            {
                //Mat_VarPrint(cells[i], 1);
                std::cout << static_cast<char*>(cells[i]->data) << '\n';
            }
            printf("}\n");
            Mat_VarFree(channels);
        }
    Mat_Close(mat);
```